# kubernetes alert using prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, alert

any idea how to set alert if any pod gets down in k8?

```yaml
  - alert: KubernetesPodNotHealthy
    expr: sum by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Unknown|Failed"}) > 0
    for: 15m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: Kubernetes Pod not healthy (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Pod has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @Tejas Mahakalkar, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are ample sources on the web to learn about how to set up an alert if any pod gets down/failed in kubernetes by yourself.

**Follow the below steps to set up alerts with Prometheus on Kubernetes :**

1. Install Prometheus Node Exporter on Kubernetes
2. Create Scraping Configs for Kubernetes Resources in Prometheus
3. Add kube-state-metrics to Prometheus
4. Add Dashboards to Grafana
5. Install Alertmanager
6. Update Prometheus Configuration to include Alertmanager
7. Create Alerting Rules
8. Load Multiple ConfigMaps into the same directory

**References :**

1. [Karim Elatov’s Blog post on Alerting with Prometheus on Kubernetes](http://elatov.github.io/2020/01/alerting-with-prometheus-on-kubernetes/)
2. [Ahmad Iqbal Ali’s](https://medium.com/@ahmadiq) Medium Blog on [Alerting in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/stakater/alerting-in-kubernetes-5df357c9b036)
3. [Bibin Wilson’s](https://devopscube.com/author/bibinwilson/) Devopscube Blog on [Setting Up Alert Manager on Kubernetes – Beginners Guide](https://devopscube.com/alert-manager-kubernetes-guide/) Prometheus Kubernetes tutorial series
4. [Mateo Burillo’s](https://sysdig.com/blog/author/mateo/) Sysdig blog on [Kubernetes monitoring with Prometheus, the ultimate guide](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/) to know the detailed kubernetes alert using prometheus.
5. [Grégoire DAYET’s](https://gregoiredayet.medium.com/) Medium Blog on [Monitoring and Alerting on your Kubernetes Cluster with Prometheus and Grafana](https://gregoiredayet.medium.com/monitoring-and-alerting-on-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-prometheus-and-grafana-55e4b427b22d)